# Override a few keycodes with XKB

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to shuffle a few keys around with XKB. (Why? On a laptop where some keys are inconveniently located.) I currently use xmodmap:

```
keycode 110 = Prior
keycode 115 = Delete
keycode 112 = Next
keycode 117 = Insert
keycode 119 = End
keycode 118 = Home
```

Instead I want to use XKB and assign different symbolic names for certain physical keys, rather than assign different keysyms to certain keycodes. ([This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/why-does-emacs-swap-backspace-and-delete-on-this-one-machine/9816#9816) is why.) I want keycode 110 to send `PGUP` instead of `HOME`, keycode 115 to send `DELE` instead of `END`, etc. The rest of the configuration must not be affected (so `PGUP` is to keep sending the keysym `Prior`, etc., and all other keys remain as they are).

How can I change the assignment of these specific keycodes? I'll load a file with `xkbcomp somefile.xkb $DISPLAY`, what do I need to put in `somefile.xkb`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a file containing your keycode changes, and save it as (for example) `~/.xkb/keycodes/local`. (The `keycodes` directory is hard-coded; the base directory can be something else, and the filename too.) This will contain in your case

```
xkb_keycodes {
  <PGUP> = 110;
  <PGDN> = 112;
  <DELE> = 115;
  <INS> = 117;
  <HOME> = 118;
  <END> = 119;
};
```

To load this, run

```
setxkbmap -print | sed -e '/xkb_keycodes/s/"[[:space:]]/+local&/' | xkbcomp -I${HOME}/.xkb - $DISPLAY
```

This outputs your current settings, adds `+local` to the `xkb_keycodes` `include` statement, and loads it into the XKB compiler, adding `~/.xkb` to the include path. (If you named your file something other than `~/.xkb/keycodes/local`, you'll obviously need to change `+local` and `-I${HOME}/.xkb}`.) That way all the other settings are preserved.

Comment: So _this_ is the expected path and way to pass it to the `-I` switch! Thanks, I was unable to figure this out from the manpage.

Comment: worked like a charm! it worked if want update xkb_symbols, just replace xkb_keycodes with it, worked

Answer (score 7):

You can start by `setxkbmap -print > somefile.xkb` to get the keymap you are using as a base, and then redefine the key names you want in the `xkb_keycodes` section like this :

```
xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes {
  include "evdev+aliases(azerty)"
  // Custom <key name> = keycode
  <INS> = 117;
  <HOME> = 118;
  <PGUP> = 110;
  <DELE> = 115;
  <END> = 119;
  <PGDN> = 112;
 };
 xkb_types { include "complete"};
 xkb_compatibility { include "complete"};
 xkb_symbols { include "pc+fr+inet(evdev)"};
 xkb_geometry { include "pc(pc104)"};
};
```

This generates warnings that some key names are assigned multiple times, but it works because only the last one count (so it's important to put the custom settings after the include). And the file have the advantage of being readable.

Another way is to dump the keymap you use into a file : `xkbcomp $DISPLAY somefile.xkb` and modify the same lines (it is the same keymap with the includes evaluated). This way there is no warnings for multiple definitions, but it is less readable.

Comment: Where are all these names (`evdev+aliases(azerty)`, etc.) coming from? I explicitly want to perform a relative change, not a full reconfiguration. Keys other than the 6 listed in the questions must not be affected, they must remain in the state they were in when I issued the command.

Comment: They come from the `setxkbmap -print`, they are files from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`. I think you have to give a whole keymap to `xkbcomp` but I could be wrong ...