# convert .Xmodmap to custom.xkb file and load it from $HOME directory - customize x keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap

I use the following .Xmodmap file to map a few symbols and German Umlaute öäü:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keycode  13 = 4 dollar EuroSign                                                
keycode  19 = 0 parenright degree
keycode  20 = minus underscore ssharp
keycode  21 = equal plus plusminus
keycode  47 = semicolon colon odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde
```

To use it I just have to add this line to my .xsessionrc file:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap &
```

Unfortunately XFCE takes too long (many seconds) to load it and so I wanted to transfer these settings to the xkb system, which XFCE uses.

But xkb seems too sophisticated to provide a similar simple solution for this simple task. How could the same be achieved with xkb?

There is already an example of how to [Override a few keycodes with XKB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb). However this is not a duplicate since my changes have to go to the xkb_symbols section and the solution needs some essential modifications. Furthermore my xkb file has to be in a folder named symbols/ e.g. ${HOME}/symbols/gergr:

```
setxkbmap -print |sed -e '/xkb_symbols/s/"[[:space:]]/+gergr&/' |xkbcomp -I${HOME} - $DISPLAY
```

I am wondering what exactly does a working xkb file look like.