# XKB: assign multiple keycodes to one behaviour (<ESC>)

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a new bluetooth keyboard, and for some reason the keycode that the escape key returns is 172 instead of 1 (according to 'showkey'; the same codes have 8 added in xkb, so 180 instead of 9). By following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb) I am able to remap ESC to work on keycode 180 instead of 9, so that's great, however I cannot seem to do it twice, i.e. write

```
    <ESC> = 9;
    <ESC> = 180;
```

In this case only the latter setting works. This is sub-optimal because it then breaks the  key on the in-built keyboard. So I can get one or the other to work fine, but not both.

What is the correct thing to do about this?

Answer (score 1):

According to *[An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/xkb.pdf)*, you can do this with an *alias*.  That feature is used in [`xkb/aliases`](https://github.com/xendk/xkb/blob/master/keycodes/aliases), so you should be able to do something like

```
alias <ESC> = 9;
alias <ESC> = 180;
```

Comment: Arg, well maybe, but that exact thing is bad! It crashed my system and made booting both normally and via recovery mode impossible. I think it was causing a segfault in some xkb library. Had to boot into a rescue console via my install disk and change it back, then got back to my original (much more minor :p) problem. Phew.

Comment: Also I don't think aliases work like that, seems more like they are designed to assign e.g. <ESC> to another symbolic name, not to multiple keycodes.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have to go through two levels of mapping. In the *keycodes mapping* you give "arbitrary" names (up to 4 chars inside `<>`) to the numeric scan-codes generated by the keyboard, then in the *symbols mapping* you say how that key name acts.  So you need to have

```
<ESC> = 9;
<ESC2> = 180;
```

then an `xkb_symbols` entry of

```
 key <ESC2>  {  [ Escape        ]   };
```

However, in your case of 2 keyboards, you should really simply set up a different layout for each keyboard instead of making a compatible one.
Use `xinput -list` to get the ids of your keyboards, and for each run `setxkbmap -device id ...` and the other arguments specifying model, layout, variant, and option for that specific keyboard.