# Reconfigure some keys at the system level

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

I wanted to know is it possible in lubuntu to change the key mappings. E.g. if I press 'i' what actually is pressed is 'o'. I need to donate this old laptop and it has non working backspace and underscore keys and I was thinking I could remap them to insert and pause break keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are using X11 tag so I assume you are speaking about XOrg.
Yes, it is possible.

In Xorg you may use either `xmodmap` or `XKB extensions`. XKB is modern but complex way.

First you need to find **keycode** of your key. You need `xev`. Run it and click button. You will see something like `keycode 31`. That is you keycode.

**xmodmap**

Please read `man xmodmap`, then execute `xmodmap -e "keycode 31 = o O"`.
That means 31 produces o and with modificator (shift) it produces capital O.

Place to permanent store this setting depends on the way you run XOrg (display manager, startx etc) but it is probably `~/.Xmodmap`. This file is simply used by something like `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from `xinitrc` or something like it.

**XKB**

You may create additional keycodes map and add it to keycodes using `setxkbmap`. See : [Override a few keycodes with XKB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb)

This doc is very good if you want to understand XKB: https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/index.html

PS:  List of all keysyms (you map keycode(31) to keysym (letter O) could be found in include `X11/keysym.h`. You need to remove `XK` prefix. For Pause (`XK_Pause`) you may map keycode to Pause etc.

Comment: someone edited the tags. i don't know what xOrg is. can you provide me with something that has step by step leyman info on how to make this work @user996142 . also since my particular keys are not working i wonder how will it be possible to get their keycodes.

Comment: Xorg is X11 implementation. If you use UI -- you use XOrg. You do not need keycodes of dead keys, you need keycodes of insert and pause. Get them using ``xev``, then check ``keysym.h`` for keysyms for backspace and underscore and try ``xmodmap``