# How to map LSGT to left control with xkb?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to map `LSGT` (the key on European keyboards) to "left control" using `xkb` with no success (under X and ubuntu 18).

I tried the following:

1. replacing the `LSGT` line with

```
    key <LSGT> { [Control_L] };
```

and adding `modifier_keys` tag before the block
in the body of the layout I use in `/usr/share/xkb/symbols/fr` (in the bepo section since this is the layout I use)

2. following roughly the step detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501659/how-to-swap-command-and-control-keys-with-xkb-step-by-step/835844) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/where-is-xkb-getting-its-configuration): more precisely I added the following code at the end of `.../xkb/symbols/ctrl`

```
partial modifier_keys alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "lsgt_lctrl" {
    key <LSGT> { [Control_L] };
};
```

(the alphanumeric tag is here because I'm not clear wether the tags refer to the key mapping or the actual keys and I guess `LSGT` is an alphanumeric key I also tried removing it)

the following line in `.../xkb/rules/evdev` under `! option = symbols`

```
ctrl:lsgt_lctrl = +ctrl(lsgt_lctrl)
```

and the following line under `! option` in evdev.lst

```
ctrl:lsgt_lctrl Use LSGT as left control
```

using `dconf` editor I added `['ctrl:lsgt_lctrl']` in the `xkb` options

Then I rebooted, since this didn't work I tried deleting everything in `/var/lib/xkb` (which contained only a `README.compiled` file) and rebooting again and it still doesn't work.

I remember using a similar-ish procedure had worked under a previous linux install so I'm confused.

Thank you for reading me, this is my first time asking a question in this type of forum and I'm fairly new to linux so let me know if I'm doing so in a wrong or annoying way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by adding the `replace` keyword in the first block of code.
It now reads

```
partial modifier_keys alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "lsgt_lctrl" {
   replace key <LSGT> { [Control_L] };
};
```

I assume there is another conflicting definition for `LSGT` elsewhere in `xkb` (?)

note: since I didn't register the first time around I don't know if I can properly indicate that this is me answering my own question or that the answer does work.

Comment: Don't worry, it is correctly registered as an answer to your own question. After a minimum waiting time, you can even accept your own answer if no answer you might consider as better has been posted in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue with the following change in /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev

```
#        <LSGT> = 94;
#        <RCTL> = 105;
        <RCTL> = 94;
```

After that, the "\&|*", known as LSGT, which occupied place of right control in my case, works as right control. The drawback is that on external keyboard, right control does not work anymore after this change.

So to have LSGT work as LCTL, try the following

```
#        <LSGT> = 94;
#        <LCTL> = 37;
        <LCTL> = 94;
```

Answer (score 0):

running `setkbdmap -print > somefile.xkb` prints the XKB config with macros/directives expanded as indicated in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/override-a-few-keycodes-with-xkb).

if you compare that with the unexpanded `setkbdmap -print` output, the problems with your config may be more clear. doing this also gives you a file with your keycodes listed in order.

after looking through that config, I found that my XKB macros/directives are not being expanded in order, causing the following lines to be evaluated after my `io(swapcaps)` and `ìo(intl)` lines have been included.

```
    key <LVL3> {
        type= "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
    key <LSGT> {
        type= "FOUR_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [ backslash, bar, backslash, bar ]
    };
```

also, if you go to Keyboard config (in the KDE system settings module), then under layouts you can generate previews of your layouts. for this situation, the previews generate better output than parsing layouts with `xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/io $DISPLAY` or `setxkbmap -config ~/.config/me/xkb/io -print -verbose 10`. once you get the preview to generate, then you should see the "< >" symbol on whichever key you mapped/replaced it with.

i'm trying to map `key <ESC> {[ LSGT ]}` or use `replace key` with the following script below, while then applying the `level5(lsgt_switch)` to get an additional modkey -- or at least get an extended range of symbols for LaTeX/Julia...

```
hidden partial
xkb_symbols "swapcaps" {
    key <ESC> {[ LSGT ]};
    key <CAPS> {[ Escape ]};
};

xkb_symbols "intl" {

    include "us(intl)"
    include "io(swapcaps)"
    include "level5(lsgt_switch)"

    name[Group1] = "Digimon - US (With Dead Keys)";

    key <SPCE> {[       space, underscore, nobreakspace, nobreakspace   ]};

    //key <TLDE> {[dead_grave, dead_tilde, grave, asciitilde ] };

    key <AE01> {[              exclam, 1,    exclamdown,      onesuperior ] };
    key <AE02> {[                  at, 2,   twosuperior, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AE03> {[          numbersign, 3, threesuperior,      dead_macron ] };
    key <AE04> {[              dollar, 4,      currency,         sterling ] };

    //// ...
};
```

Some notes on pc104 & pc105 keycodes:

- the only keycode that the pc104 keyboard lacks is `93`, which immediately precedes `key <LSGT> = 94`. i'm still running into problems. but it's strange this key is even defined there, since the only difference between `pc104` and `pc105` is the added `LSGT` key.
- i can't seem to find the actual pc105 definition, which only seems to exist in `$XKB/symbols/pc` as symbols.

Comment: oh and setting your keyboard to a UK or European variant may solve the problem. I need to reboot to see if the `pc105` keycodes and `uk(intl)` symbols together will allow me to map on top of them.